# php form handling for select drop down list

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form in a php file that I only need a drop down list.  I will have 3 options in the list and 1 submit button.  When the option is chosen and the submit button is hit, I need it to open a .txt file from the root directory.  So in short, each option opens up a different .txt file on the same page  I feel like I would need to pass a value through a function to get the txt file to open.  I am looking for ideas on how to implement this....

thank you

Comment: do  you want to open that page or redirect to that page?

Comment: not sure....I dont want to leave the page the form is on....the txt files will open on the same page,,,just below the form

Comment: Don't use `.txt`, use some `JSON`

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps

1.Create a drop down with file identifier =>option name pair
2.On submit form  execute the code

```
switch(file_identifier_name){
case "some_thing":
$filepath="";
$filename="";
break;
}

//force download  
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");

//disposition / encoding on response body
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

//Remember to user correct file path
echo file_get_contents($filepath.$filename);
```

Comment: is there not a way to assign variable to the value, and use if else statements ....(if $option1 open file1.txt....or something like this...?

Comment: create a mapping array like this      $files=array('file1.text',=>'file2.text');  now $files[0] gives you file1.text n so on